# INSERT INTO ... SELECT with more SELECT columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-insert

## Thank you for your time.

I have a INSERT INTO ... SELECT setup, but I also want to filter using extra columns (that do not exist in the table I am inserting into)

For example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (t1_col1, t1_col2, t1_col3)
SELECT
  t2.t1_col1,
  t2.t1_col2,
  t3.t1_col3,
  t4.filter_col
FROM table2 t2
  INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.t1_col1 = t3.t1_col1
  INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.filter_col = t2.filer_col
WHERE t4.filter_col = 'value';
```

**table1** only has columns *t1_col1*, *t1_col2* and *t1_col3* so when I attempt to run this it fails as expected:

```
ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
```

So my question is, how can I still include the filter, but specify which columns from my SELECT statement should be used in the INSERT INTO statement.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Just don't select `t4.filter_col`, you can still use it in the `where` clause.

Comment: You don't need to put `t4.filter_col` in the SELECT columns in order to use it in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to same number of column in select ,so remove `t4.filter_col` from selection

```
INSERT INTO table1 (t1_col1, t1_col2, t1_col3)
SELECT
  t2.t1_col1,
  t2.t1_col2,
  t3.t1_col3      
FROM table2 t2
  INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.t1_col1 = t3.t1_col1
  INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.filter_col = t2.filer_col
WHERE t4.filter_col = 'value';
```

**Note: you are not bound to select all columns those you used in join or filter**

Answer (score 1):

It's almost right, but you select one column too much. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (t1_col1, t1_col2, t1_col3)
SELECT
  t2.t1_col1,
  t2.t1_col2,
  t3.t1_col3
FROM table2 t2
  INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.t1_col1 = t3.t1_col1
  INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.filter_col = t2.filer_col
WHERE t4.filter_col = 'value';
```